# PHP - Checar se existem parâmetros GET em uma URL

Tags: php

Boa noite!

Essa dúvida fica mais para curiosidade.

Tenho uma página em php que exibe certos tópicos de um fórum phpbb. Entre os dados armazenados está o caminho (url) do tópico, que vem no formato `http://meusite.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=yy&t=xx`. Pelo pouco que eu sei o `f` e o `t` são requisições GET.

Pretendo concatenar nessa string os parâmetros do Google Analytics (o que eu poderia fazer sem verificar integridade simplesmente adicionando `&utm_blablabal...`), mas aí fiquei pensando: e se eu mudar a estrutura dos links (tipo via url_rewrite)? Ou se por algum motivo ambos os formatos (com/sem GET) passarem a ser armazenados pelo PHPBB? Alguns links obviamente viriam quebrados (por "abrir" a parte da requisição usando um & em vez de um ?), e assim necessitaria de uma verificação.

O que eu quero fazer é simplesmente checar nessa string se existem variáveis GET como essas (pro caso de um dia eu alterar o esquema das URLs e assim os links não quebrarem) e, dependendo da existência ou não, adicionar um `&` ou um `?` antes dos parâmetros do Analytics. Basicamente uma "verificação de integridade".

Grato pela ajuda, e desculpem se não fui claro.

Answer (score 1):

Simples. Você pode contar o que está no $_GET

```
empty($_GET)
```

Ou

```
(count($_GET) > 0)
```

Se for de uma url especifica, faça assim

```
strlen(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)) > 0
```

Comment: Espera... o $_GET não é reservado à requisições? Porque essa URL não está "vindo" de uma requisição HTTP. É uma string que está armazenada em um banco (do PHPBB) e eu preciso apenas checar se existe parametros do estilo GET nela, para poder inserir os adicionais do adsense sem repetir o ?.

Answer (score 0):

Para quebrar sua string que representa uma URL você pode utilizar os métodos [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

`parse_url()` recebe uma string que representa uma URL e quebra a string em componentes. Dada sua URL de exemplo `http://meusite.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=yy&t=xx` `parse_url()` retorna:

```
array(4) {
  'scheme' =>
  string(4) "http"
  'host' =>
  string(14) "meusite.com.br"
  'path' =>
  string(20) "/forum/viewtopic.php"
  'query' =>
  string(9) "f=yy&t=xx"
}
```

`parse_str()` recebe uma query string, string com parâmetros GET, e quebra em um array com chaves e valores. Dada a query string da URL acima `f=yy&t=xx`, o método retorna:

```
array(2) {
  'f' =>
  string(2) "yy"
  't' =>
  string(2) "xx"
}
```

E para reconstruir sua URL após adicionar um novo parâmetro GET (ou modificar um já existente) você pode utilizar:

- o método [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php), que recebe um array associativo (array com chaves e valores), para reconstruir a query string;
- + uma simples concatenação de strings para reconstruir a URL a partir dos componentes da mesma que você pegou com `parse_url()` e a query string que você refez no passo acima.

Abaixo, o código completo para quebrar uma URL, adicionar parâmetros GET e reconstruir a URL novamente:

```
<?php

$url_string = 'http://meusite.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=yy&t=xx';

// quebrando a URL em partes
$url_partes = parse_url($url_string);

// quebrando os parâmetros GET da URL
parse_str($url_partes['query'], $parametros_get);

// adicionando novo parâmetro GET
$parametros_get['novoParametro'] = 'VALOR';

// reconstruindo a query string (os parâmetros GET juntos)
$url_partes['query'] = http_build_query($parametros_get);

// reconstruindo a URL
$url_string = $url_partes['scheme'] . '://' . $url_partes['host'] . $url_partes['path'] . '?' . $url_partes['query'];

echo $url_string . "\n";
```

vai printar:

```
http://meusite.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=yy&t=xx&novoParametro=VALOR
```